# No email arrived issue when I use javax.mail

Tags: android, kotlin, email, jakarta-mail, sendmail

I am making android app with kotlin. I want to send email with my gmail account so I used javax.mail package. And now I faced an issue to send gmail. following is full content of my Notify.kt file.

```
package com.facecool.utils

import android.graphics.Bitmap
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream
import java.util.Properties
import javax.activation.DataHandler
import javax.activation.DataSource
import javax.mail.Authenticator
import javax.mail.Message
import javax.mail.Multipart
import javax.mail.Part
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart
import javax.mail.util.ByteArrayDataSource


internal object Notify {
    fun sendEmail(
        subject: String?,
        message: String?,
        recipientEmail: String?,
        bmp: Bitmap?
    ) {
        if (recipientEmail == null || recipientEmail.isEmpty()) return
        try {
            val yourMail = "example@gmail.com"
            val yourPwd = "password"
            val properties = getProperties()
            properties["mail.debug"] = "false"

            // Create a session with authentication
            val session: Session = Session.getInstance(properties, object : Authenticator() {
                override fun getPasswordAuthentication(): PasswordAuthentication {
                    return PasswordAuthentication(
                        yourMail,
                        yourPwd
                    )
                }
            })

                val mimeMessage: MimeMessage? = createMimeMessage(
                    session, yourMail, recipientEmail, subject, message,
                    bmp!!
                )
                Transport.send(mimeMessage)
        } catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
 
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    fun getProperties(): Properties {

        val properties = Properties()
  
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com")
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587")
            properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true")
            properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com")
        
        return properties
    }
    
    private fun getImageData(bmp: Bitmap): ByteArray? {
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
        return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
    }
    
    fun createMimeMessage(
        session: Session?,
        yourMail: String,
        recipientEmail: String,
        subject: String?,
        message: String?,
        bmp: Bitmap
    ): MimeMessage? {
        try {
            val mimeMessage = MimeMessage(session)
            mimeMessage.setFrom(InternetAddress(yourMail))
            if (!recipientEmail.isEmpty()) mimeMessage.setRecipient(
                Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress(recipientEmail)
            )
            mimeMessage.setSubject(subject)

            // Add text part to the multipart
            val multipart: Multipart = MimeMultipart("mixed")
            val textPart = MimeBodyPart()
            textPart.setText(message)
            multipart.addBodyPart(textPart)
            
            //add Recognized Image
            val filePart = MimeBodyPart()
            filePart.setFileName("Recognized Face.jpg")
            filePart.setDisposition(Part.ATTACHMENT)
            val source: DataSource = ByteArrayDataSource(getImageData(bmp), "image/jpeg")
            filePart.setDataHandler(DataHandler(source))
            multipart.addBodyPart(filePart)
            
            //end
            mimeMessage.setContent(multipart)
            return mimeMessage
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

After I called the `sendEmail` method, no email arrives.
I used my gmail address and its sign in password. Do I need to use 2-step authentication for gmail?
Please let me know if my code has an issue.

I checked that the ‘javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials l25-20020a2e8699000000b002c9f16d5da9sm1127595lji.95 - gsmtp’ is occured. How to fix this issue?

Comment: You likely need to set up an app password for your google account:

https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

Comment: @Brian_Entei Yeah, You are right. Someone told me about that. Thank you for your help.